# How to get substring from invariant string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have column where Loan Number is saved but data in that column is varying and I have to get substring from such string. examples are

```
RF01234-001-9   
CFF 01234-012-5
DSL---01234-188-5
```

In all above cases substring should return "01234" and another substring should return "001", "012", "188".

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: What denotes that it is `'01234'` you are after? What is the logic to identify the Loan Number? Seems like, as well, you should be fixing the data to follow a standardised format. Perhaps you should consider doing that and implementing a `CONSTRAINT` to ensure formatting is adhered to in the future.

Comment: Also, please avoid "moving the goal posts" after you've started receiving answers. It can often attract downvotes in your question (especially if it invalidates existing answers), and unfortunately only serves to waste the time of those that have already put in effort to answering your question. The last sentence you have added, for example, now makes Gordon's answer incomplete even though it (might have) been correct at the time of answering.

Comment: Is the loan number always in the format `00000-000-0`? Could it have any other format? could there be more than one in a string? If so, what value would you be after?

Comment: these are the only formats in which it is saved.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want the first 5 digits in the string.  If so:

```
select substring(str, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', str), 5)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6e97afa46114c5c9c134eb8455ea530) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Thank you. your solution works. I have updated my question. I also need middle substring as well.

Comment: @SyedImranShah that should have been part of your original question. Don't update questions and invalid existing answers. Take the time to explain the problem, in full, from get go.

Comment: Larnu Okay for the future.